# SpriteKit - Using a loop to create multiple sprites. How do I give each sprite a different variable name?

Tags: objective-c, loops, sprite, sprite-kit

I am using SpriteKit.

The code below basically makes a lattice of dots on the screen. However, I want to call each 'dot' a different name based on its position, so that I can access each dot individually in another method. I'm struggling a little on this, so would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
#define kRowCount 8
#define kColCount 6
#define kDotGridSpacing CGSizeMake (50,-50)
#import "BBMyScene.h"

@implementation BBMyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    // Background
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.957 green:0.957 blue:0.957 alpha:1]; /*#f4f4f4*/



        CGPoint baseOrigin = CGPointMake(35, 385);
        for (NSUInteger row = 0; row < kRowCount; ++row) {


            CGPoint dotPosition = CGPointMake(baseOrigin.x, row * (kDotGridSpacing.height) + baseOrigin.y);


            for (NSUInteger col = 0; col < kColCount; ++col) {

                SKSpriteNode *dot = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dot"];
                dot.position = dotPosition;
                [self addChild:dot];
                //6
                dotPosition.x += kDotGridSpacing.width;
            }
        }
    }

return self;
```

}

Here is an image of what appears on screen when I run the above code...
http://cl.ly/image/3q2j3E0p1S1h/Image1.jpg

I simply want to be able to call an individual dot to do something when there is some form of user interaction, and I'm not sure how I would do that without each dot having a different name.

If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
for(SKNode *node in self.children){
    if ([node.name containsString:@"sampleNodeName"]) {
            [node removeFromParent];
        }
   }
}
```

Hope this one helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `name` property of each node inside the loop.
Then you can access them with `self.children[index]`.

If you want to find a specific node in your children, you have to enumerate through the array.

**Update**:

To clarify how to search for an item by iterating, here is a helper method:

```
- (SKNode *)findNodeNamed:(NSString *)nodeName
{
    SKNode *nodeToFind = nil;

    for(SKNode *node in self.children){
        if([node.name isEqualToString:nodeName]){
            nodeToFind = node;
            break;
        }
    }];
    return nodeToFind;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I go about that?

dot.name = ?

Comment: Yes, inside the loop.

Comment: But in your case you should be able to drop it and only compare to the coordinates? (since you know where they are)

Comment: Thanks.

`dot.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dot_%d_%d", row, col];` is perfect for naming it. 

How can I then access it? For example, if I wanted to log the location of a specific dot?